# Nginx rule for specific URL's

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting, proxy, rule

I have this url group on my website

```
mywebsite.com.br/

mywebsite.com.br/sao-paulo/sp

mywebsite.com.br/rio-de-janeiro/rj

mywebsite.com.br/natal/rn

mywebsite.com.br/aparecida-do-rio-doce/go
```

...

In total, are 5561 different urls. There is a way to send the same html file for all of those urls? But, there is some others URL that must forwarded to my nodejs server, like this ones:

```
    mywebsite.com.br/update-password/1234

    mywebsite.com.br/update-password/

    mywebsite.com.br/user/confirm

    mywebsite.com.br/user/confirm/123

    mywebsite.com.br/api/v1/auth/facebook

    mywebsite.com.br/api/v1/auth/local

    mywebsite.com.br/api/v1/user/new

    mywebsite.com.br/api/v1/user/statistics
```

How can I set a Nginx pattern to serve the same html file for the first group of urls (5561 different urls), and forward to my nodejs server the second group?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a map:

```
map $uri $forward2nodejs {
    ~^/update-password/ 1;
    ~^/user/confirm 1;
    ~^/api/v1/auth/ 1;
    ~^/api/v1/user/ 1;
}

server {
    server_name mywebsite.com.br;

    # default location for the 5561 different urls
    location / {
        try_files /default.html =404;
    }

    if ($forward2nodejs) {
        return 301 http://nodejs;       
    }
}
```

Here's another using proxy_pass in prefix locations:

```
server {
    server_name mywebsite.com.br;

    # default location for the 5561 different urls
    location / {
        try_files /default.html =404;
    }

    location /update-password/ {
        include nodejs_proxy_pass;       
    }

    location /user/confirm {
        include nodejs_proxy_pass;       
    }

    location /api/v1/auth/ {
        include nodejs_proxy_pass;       
    }

    location /api/v1/user/ {
        include nodejs_proxy_pass;       
    }
}
```

Comment: putnamhill thanks for your answer, it's almost what I need. I need to do a proxy_pass to my nodejs server running locally, to the urls that match the $forward2nodejs map pattern, not a redirect 301. is it possible?

Comment: Since proxy_pass is not allowed in an if statement, you would need to try something different. I would suggest prefix locations with an included file with your nodes proxy_pass directives. I'll add it to my answer so you can see what that would look like.